# Area under a curve by using a different method

Tags: curves

Can the area under a curve be computed by stretching the curve into a straight line(of same length) and also by keeping the base and the opposite side of the original lengths?

Comment: Have you tried to draw some pictures to decide this?

Comment: This will not conserve area in general. And you cannot keep the base, sides and curve the same original lengths and straighten the curve. Something will have to change in length.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/f6QPELPG2e96qB4R8